# What is the current consensus on the Loveheim Cube of Emotion

Tags: endocrinology, neurology

I recently encountered the [Lovheim Cube of Emotion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B6vheim_cube_of_emotion). I was wondering what level of supporting research there is to go with it and whether or not there is a concensus at this stage.

If I'm perfectly honest, I'm skeptical, the evidence that I've seen is uncompelling and the model over simplistic but maybe I've missed something.

Comment: What research have you done into this, and can you tell us what you found? Your link states, "While the validity of the model remains unverified ..." Thanks.

Comment: That's part of the problem, barring that wikipedia page I've struggled to find any scholarly resources discussing this in any depth. I tend to take wikipedia articles with a strong pinch of salt since they rarely represent active research very well.

Comment: @JamesHughes What about the resources cited on the wikipedia page, and all of their citing articles? This isn't my area of expertise within neuroscience, but from a very cursory overview it seems like it has gotten a lot more traction in models for artificial emotional systems rather than explaining actual biological emotion; I suspect this may be partly because there is no spatial component. The monoamines are not hormones in the nervous system, they are neuromodulators or neurotransmitters, so spatial components matter a lot. Simplifying it to a cube based on concentration ignores space.